# Using GridSearchCV for NLP Missing Positional Argument Self

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, data-science

I am working on a NLP problem. I've been testing various models and the process has been working fine.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
classifier = SGDClassifier().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
y_predicted_tfidf = classifier.predict(X_test_tfidf)
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
precision = precision_score(y_test, y_predicted_tfidf, pos_label=None,average='weighted')
print(precision)
>>> 0.79708294305
```

Now I am trying to employ Grid Search in order find tune parameters and running into an error.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = {'alpha': [0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.01] }
gs_classifier = GridSearchCV(SGDClassifier, parameters, n_jobs=-1)
gs_classifier = gs_classifier.fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
```

Which results in the following output:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-95b85f78662f> in <module>()
      1 gs_classifier = GridSearchCV(SGDClassifier, parameters, n_jobs=-1)
----> 2 gs_classifier = gs_classifier.fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)

anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups)
    943             train/test set.
    944         """
--> 945         return self._fit(X, y, groups,                                      
...
/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     65                             % (repr(estimator), type(estimator)))
     66     klass = estimator.__class__
---> 67     new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
     68     for name, param in six.iteritems(new_object_params):
     69         new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)

TypeError: get_params() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I've tried various combinations of parameters and all result in the same error. For this example I've kept it simple and am just using a range of alpha values.

Comment: Did you perhaps forget the `fit` method, e.g. does `gs_classifier = gs_classifier.fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)` work?

Comment: Yes, I did. Now that I have updated it, it seems I am missing a value in my parameters dictionary. TypeError: get_params() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self

Comment: You aren't properly passing your `SGDClassifier()` object (which you have labeled as `classifier`) when you create your GridSearchCV object. I believe the line you want to use is: `gs_classifier = GridSearchCV(classifier, parameters, n_jobs=-1)`

Comment: You are correct! Just passing it in as SGDClassifier() instead of SGDClassifier eliminates the error.